# How to resolve Import failed: Circular dependency

Tags: magento, magento2, circular-dependency

i got stuck in this error

**Import failed: Circular dependency: Magento\Logging\Model\Handler\Controllers depends on Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory and vice versa.**

help me i am stuck from 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Disabling 'Magento_Logging' in `app/etc/config.php` will make it possible to at least run `setup:upgrade` without errors:

```php
'Magento_Logging' => 0,
```